# On topological space $ X =(0,1) ^{2}$ with dictionary order topology find the weight of the space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

On topological space $ X =(0,1) ^{2}$  with dictionary order topology find the weight of the space $X$.
I am simply stuck don't even know where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\langle 0, 1 \rangle^2$ in this case?

Comment: I meant unit square without the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean $(0,1)^2$ (from the comments) and the open sets $\{x\} \times (0,1), x \in (0,1)$ (open intervals between $(x,0)$ and $(x,1)$ so they're order-open) are non-empty and pairwise disjoint. So any base has size at least $|(0,1)|=\mathfrak{c}$. The standard base for that space (open intervals) also has that size so $w((0,1)^2) = \mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret X as (0,1)×(0,1) in the dictionary order.
For a start, a base for X is
{ ((r,x), (r,y)) : r in R, x,y in Q $\cap\ $ (0,1), x < y }.